# Teams auth popup wont close or redirect after completing sign in (React)

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a React app (with React Router) running inside of a MS Teams tab, and I'm trying to have the user sign-in with azure ad redirect. A popup opens when they click the sign in button, but when they finish the auth procedure, the redirect happens inside the popup instead of closing and redirecting back to the tab.

When the sign-in button is clicked this runs inside of the SignIn component:

```
function loginTeams() {
  microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({
    url: window.location.origin + "/teams-auth",
    width: 600,
    height: 535,
    successCallback: function (result) {
      console.log('success')
    },
    failureCallback: function (reason) {
      console.log('failed')
    }
  });
}
```

Then it redirects to the TeamsAuth component which opens the popup:

```
useEffect(() => {
  microsoftTeams.initialize();
  microsoftTeams.getContext(function (context) {
    let authorizeEndpoint = buildAzureSSOLink(context);
    window.location.assign(authorizeEndpoint);
  });
}, []);
```

The redirect uri is set to /teams-auth-end which redirects to the TeamsAuthEnd component,
which calls the notify success method:

```
const queryParams = parseQueryParams(location);

useEffect(() => {
  microsoftTeams.initialize();
  microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess({
    accessToken: queryParams.access_token
  })
}, []);
```

I suspect the problem has to do with calling microsoftTeams.initialize() in more than one spot, but removing them stops the popup from opening. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, adding microsoftTeams.initialize() multiple time seems to be issue. Can you please see the code flow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-tab-aad)

Comment: Calling microsoft.initialize() in the root component, and no where else, solved my problem, thanks.