# Why is my Microsoft Teams custom app staying in the login popup window?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I'm currently deploying my (React) web app in a Microsoft Teams custom app. More specifically, I'm trying to use Azure AD SSO to log my users. I'm using the `@microsoft/teams-js` package to generate a login popup window, which works just fine. But when I login inside this popup window, the logged in session in my application is opened in this popup while the main window, inside Microsoft Teams, stays on the login page. If I refresh my custom app, I'm properly logged in though.

Here's how I use the authenticate method when I click the login button :

```js
onClick={
              isDisplayedInTeams()
                ? async (): Promise<void> => {
                    try {
                      await microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({
                        url: "/loginUrl",
                        width: 600,
                        height: 555,
                        isExternal: true,
                      });
                    } catch (error) {
                      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                      console.log(
                        "Application could not connect in Teams : ",
                        error
                      );
                    }
                  }
                : (): void => {
                    window.open("/loginUrl", "_self");
                  }
            }
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Note : I'm using Teams in my browser for now.

Edit : I just found this question which seems related : [Teams auth popup wont close or redirect after completing sign in (React)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62329833/teams-auth-popup-wont-close-or-redirect-after-completing-sign-in-react)
But I only call `initialize()` once... In a `useEffect` though.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're calling `...authentication.authenticate` and not `...authentication.getAuthToken`?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow because this is what I found when searching for method to open a login popup. Is this wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Per the discussion in comments above, it's most likely you're using `...authentication.authenticate` just because of an old example you've found. Even the other post you refer to is circa 2020. Microsoft changed and simplified the process of implementing SSO by a lot, if I recall it was later that same year. Please refer to the docs - the guidance is reasonably good and with the new model it's much quicker and easier to get this right - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-overview

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can't find a way to make `getAuthToken()` to work with our current auth process, I can't give it the redirect URL.

Comment: You don't need a redirect url any more - it's all built in in the new model. Follow the guide in a new sample project and it will be more clear.